How do I trigger a specific repository dispatch?
I have 2 workflows under 1 repo. When I send a post request, it triggers both workflows and runs both. I want to specify on my payload to trigger that specific workflow.
Currently these are the 2 GitHub Actions workflows:
on:
  repository_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Check User
        if: github.event_name == 'repository_dispatch' && github.event.client_payload.workflow_file == 'test1.yml'

on:
  repository_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Check User
        if: github.event_name == 'repository_dispatch' && github.event.client_payload.workflow_file == 'test2.yml'


These are my 2 requests:
{
  "event_type": "{{issue.key}}",
  "client_payload": {
    "workflow_file": "test1.yml"
  }
}

{
  "event_type": "{{issue.key}}",
  "client_payload": {
    "workflow_file": "test2.yml"
  }
}


However, running either post requests triggers for workflows to run.

Do you now about the workflow_dispatch concept? It would allow you to trigger a specific dispatch by event / api.

If you still want to use the repository_dispatch, you could use the event_type in the filter in your step if condition, which would look like this in your case: if: github.event.action != '{{issue.key}}'. However, you would need to use a different event_type for each request.

I've got an example here where I sent the request with an event_type = Formula Workflow Response from here

@GuiFalourd much appreciated. I ended up using workflow_dispatch and works.

You could use the workflow_dispatch concept. This would allow you to trigger a specific workflow by event / cli or api.
If you still need to use the repository_dispatch trigger, you could use the event_type in the filter in your step if condition, which would look like this in your case:
if: github.event.action != '{{issue.key}}'

However, you would need to use a different event_type for each request.
Note: I've got an example here where I sent the request with an event_type = Formula Workflow Response from here.
